# Column sort only works on the active page of Tables in DataGrid Mui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Unable to sort the whole table pages using DataGrid,it only sorts the current displayed pages,i am facing the similar issue,explain here [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901786/materialui-datagrid-sorting-only-sorts-and-shows-items-for-the-current-page)

If you sort the table, it only sorts the current page of the table and ignore all other pages of the table.